# PHP regex match only specific elements

Tags: php, regex

My HTML is:

```
<li>
    <a href="/prod_1"></a>
    <img src="/preview_1.jpg" data-image-href="//cdn.example.com/zoom_1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/prod_2"></a>
    <img src="/preview_2.jpg" data-image-href="//cdn.example.com/zoom_2.jpg" />
</li>
...
```

I am using this regex:

```
/(src|href)=("[^"]+")/siU
```

Results are:

```
[2][0] => "/prod_1"
[2][1] => "/preview_1.jpg"
[2][2] => "//cdn.example.com/zoom_1.jpg"
[2][3] => "/prod_2"
[2][4] => "/preview_2.jpg"
[2][5] => "//cdn.example.com/zoom_2.jpg"
...
```

After adding `<img.*` to the start of the regex, results obtained are distorted. I need match `src` and `href` attributes only inside `IMG` elements. What is the right way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit the matched characters to `[^>]` (not a closing anlge bracket) and only get the `img` attributes:

```
(?:<img\s*?|(?<!^)\G)\s*?([^>=]+)="([^"]*?)"(?=.*?\/>)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP3nI5/3).

Adding PHP sample code:

```
$re = "/(?:<img\\s*?|(?<!^)\\G)\\s*?([^>=]+)=\"([^\"]*?)\"(?=.*?\\/>)/siU"; 
$str = "<li>\n    <a href=\"/prod_1\"></a>\n    <img src=\"/preview_1.jpg\" data-image-href=\"//cdn.example.com/zoom_1.jpg\" />\n</li>\n<li>\n    <a href=\"/prod_2\"></a>\n    <img src=\"/preview_2.jpg\" data-image-href=\"//cdn.example.com/zoom_2.jpg\" />\n</li>"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: This result hasn't src and href attributes separately

Comment: This should work as expected extracting all attributes with their values.